# Cucumber не воспринимает таблицы

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

Я пишу тесты с использованием Cucumber, если вместо `<koef>` я вручную указываю параметры, то тест проходит правильно, но как только пытаюсь использовать таблицу тест перестает компилироваться с ошибкой

> Error parsing feature file koef_from_main.feature

```
Сценарий: Сценарий один
    Допустим я на главной странице
    Когда я вхожу с правами администратора
    И я выбираю "<koef>" коэффициентов
    Тогда "<koef>" коэффициента появляются в таблице
    И "<koef>" коэффициентов правильно сохраняются
    Примеры:
      | koef |
      | 2    |
      | 3    |
      | 4    |
```

Answer (score 0):

Может быть такой вариант вам нужен?

```
Scenario Outline: text
    Given text '<test>' text
    When text
    Then text
    Examples:
    |test|
    |1|
    |2|
    |3|
```

Answer (score 0):

[Ответ diazolin88](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/569622/356597) верный, просто написан на английской версии синтаксиса Gherkin.

В вашем сценарии ошибка синтаксиса, потому что если вы хотите перебирать варианты его выполнения с помощью "Примеров", то ключевое слово в начале должно быть не "Сценарий:", а "Структура сценария:". Вот так:

```
Структура сценария: Сценарий один
    Допустим я на главной странице
    Когда я вхожу с правами администратора
    И я выбираю "<koef>" коэффициентов
    Тогда "<koef>" коэффициента появляются в таблице
    И "<koef>" коэффициентов правильно сохраняются

    Примеры:
      | koef |
      | 2    |
      | 3    |
      | 4    |
```

Взято из [официальной документации](https://cucumber.io/docs/gherkin/reference/)

Советую пользоваться плагином Cucumber для IntelliJ IDEA, чтобы видеть подсказки по синтаксису.